# How to update map with listbuffers as values in scala?

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I want to find a shortest path from source to target in graph. In implementing of it I used `Map`:

```
var predecessors : Map[VertexId, ListBuffer[VertexId]] = Map()
```

But when I try to update it:

```
predecessors = predecessors.updated(t, predecessors.getOrElse(t, ListBuffer.empty[VertexId]) :+ v)
```

I got error

```
Expression of type Map[graphx.VertexId, ListBuffer[_ >: graphx.VertexId]] doesn't conform to expected 

type Map[graphx.VertexId, ListBuffer[graphx.VertexId]]
```

I checked some similar questions here but didn't find the answer. How should I do it properly?

Comment: It looks like `v` might not be the correct/expected type.

Answer (score 0):

That's because ListBuffer is not contravariant! and the `updated` function on map, takes a key of type VertexId which is fine, and another argument which is of type:

```
V1 >: VertexId // super type of VertexId
```

so I suggest you use List[+T] which is contravariant instead of ListBuffer.

Comment: I did as you say, and got error `Expression of type Map[graphx.VertexId, List[Any]] doesn't conform to expected type Map[graphx.VertexId, List[shapeless.T]]`

Comment: @Nourless, Did you indicate the type of `predecessors` to be Map[VertexId, List[VertexId] ]?